# Найти сумму Х наименьших элементов массива

Tags: c++

Для одномернго массива С(n) найти сумму К наименьших элементов, где 0<=n<=45.
Массив выводит, сумму не считает. Не могу разобраться где ошибка.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () 
{
   const   int   n=45;
   int  C[n];
   int   i, S=0;
   short int k;

      cout<<"Input k"<<endl;
      cin>>k;

   cout<<"Massiv V"<<endl;
   for ( i=0; i<n; i++)
       {  C[i]=rand ( ) % 45; 
          cout<<C[i]<<"    "; 
       } cout<<endl; 

    for  (i=0;  i<k;  i++)
    if ( C[i]<k) 
        S +=C[i];
   cout<<"Result    Summa="<< S<< endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас тут проблема с логикой:

```
for  (i=0;  i<k;  i++)
    if ( C[i]<k) 
        S +=C[i];
```

Вы просматриваете `k` первых элементов массива (уже не правильно, массив то не отсортированный). Дальше вы зачем-то сравниваете элемент массива с `k`.

Предполагаю, что это какое-то учебное задание, тогда логика может быть такой:

1. Сортируйте массив.
2. Складывайте `k` элементов.

Как-то так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main () {
   const   int   n=45;
   int  C[n];
   int   i, S=0;
   short int k;

   cout<<"Input k"<<endl;
   cin>>k;

   cout<<"Massiv V"<<endl;
   for ( i=0; i<n; i++){  
     C[i]=rand ( ) % 45; 
     cout<<C[i]<<"    "; 
   } cout<<endl; 

   std::sort(std::begin(С), std::end(С));

   for  (i=0;  i<k;  i++)
       S +=C[i];
   cout<<"Result    Summa="<< S<< endl;
   return 0;
}
```